# What's the standard way to add a selectable config item with ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know the standard way to build something like this (see `Manage Labels` entry in the picture):

[image]

Does it look like this?

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item (click)="selectLabelsOption()">
    Manage labels
    <p>{{selectedLabelsOption}}</p>
  </button>
<ion-list>
```

Then when you click on the row, an alert is displayed like this:

[image]

How do you achieve this?

With an alert controller that contains a cancel button and a handler on each radio button?

Or is there another component for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ion-select`:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Chose Assist App</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="choice">
    <ion-option value="a">Google App</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="b">Clip Layer</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="b">None</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

See the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/).